# Combining Two List in Kotlin with Index

Tags: kotlin

There is a data class as fruits.

```
data class Fruits(
    val code: String, //Unique
    val name: String
)
```

The base list indexed items with boolean variable is as below.

```
val indexList: MutableList<Boolean> = MutableList(baseFruitList.size) { false }
```

Now the Favourite Indexed list is as below

```
val favList: MutableList<Boolean> = MutableList(favFruitList.size) { true}
```

I want a combined full list which basically has the fav item indicated as true.

```
Ex: 
baseFruitList = {[FT1,apple],[FT2,grapes],[FT3,banana],[FT4,mango],[FT5,pears]}
favList = {[FT2,grapes],[FT4,mango]}
```

The final index list should have

```
finalIndexed = {false,true,false,true,false}
```

How can we achieve in Kotlin, without iterating through each element.

Comment: Your comment says `code` is unique, but is `name`? Can you have two things with the same code but different names and they should be considered the same thing?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have updated the Ex. with more details. I hope it is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: The change doesn’t answer my question. What if there is a `[FT6,grapes]`? Is it considered one of the favorites or not? What about `[FT2,apple]`, or is that impossible to exist?

Comment: @Tenfour04 It won't be possible to have [FT2,apple]. The combination is basically unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
val finalIndexed = baseFruitList.map { it in favList }
```

assuming, like @Tenfour04 is asking, that `name` is guaranteed to be a specific value (including matching case) for a specific `code` (since that combination is how a data class matches another, e.g. for checking if it's in another list)

If you can't guarantee that, this is safer:

```
val finalIndexed = baseFruitList.map { fruit ->
    favList.any { fav.code == fruit.code }
}
```

but here you have to iterate over all the favs (at least until you find a match) looking to see if one has the code.

But really, if `code` is the unique identifier here, why not just store those in your `favList`?

```
favList = listOf("FT2", "FT4") // or a Set would be more efficient, and more correct!
val finalIndexed = baseFruitList.map { it.code in favList }
```

I don't know what you mean about "without iterating through each element" - if you mean without an explicit indexed for loop, then you can use these simple functions like I have here. But there's always some amount of iteration involved. Sets are always an option to help you minimise that